# Prove the inequality $2|xy|≤x^2+y^2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

As far as I know, there are no special conditions other than this is a space with only real numbers. I'm not sure how to move forward with the problem. I know that $x^2 = |x|^2$ but I don't know how to make use of that.

$2|xy|≤ x^2 + y^2$

Comment: Since squares are non-negative, can you find something which you can square which might have some terms which look like the ones in your inequality?

Answer (score 12):

Note that
$$0\leq (|x|-|y|)^2 = x^2 -2|xy| +y^2.$$

Comment: So, using this I would just add 2|xy| to the side with the zero and it's proved?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

By AM-GM $$x^2+y^2\geq2\sqrt{x^2y^2}=2|xy|.$$

Also, we can use the Rearrangement:
$$a^2+b^2=|a|^2+|b|^2\geq |a||b|+|b||a|=2|ab|.$$

Comment: I think it's unlikely that someone who doesn't know how to prove the inequality would know about AM-GM inequality. The easiest (IMO) proof of AM-GM is to prove this in the first place !

Comment: @Arnaud D Is there some mistake in my proof? Why did you down-vote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, that must have been someone else. There is no mistake, it's just that to me your answer is a bit "backward" : I learned this inequality first and then learned to use it to prove AM-GM. Viewed this way, your answer is a case of circular reasoning. You can prove AM-GM in other ways and make this valid, but I think it's a lot easier to just use the square argument in Yannik's answer.

Comment: @Arnaud D. I have found a proof without the formula $(a-b)^2=a^2+b^2-2ab.$ What do you think?

Comment: It seems to me that the proof of the Rearrangement inequality, applied to this special case, would be exactly the same argument...

Comment: @Arnaud D Yes of course, but we got it immediately. Also, I think it's better to think by AM-GM or by Rearrangement or more than always to prove all statement. Sometimes it's really unnecessary like in our case.

Comment: Why is |a|^2 + |b|^2 \geq |a||b| + |b||a|? What rearrangement was that?

Comment: Also. I think you now have to prove AM-GM in order for that first proof to be complete

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2+y^2-2|xy|=\min(x^2+y^2-2xy,x^2+y^2+2xy)\ge0.$$